# Firebase Firestore rules: will get()'ing the document being checked counted as another read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a code in Firestore security rules like this (showing only relevant parts):

```
match /users/{userId} {
    function isUserDisabled(userId) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId))
                    .data.admin == true;
    }

    allow read:  if true;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                 && !isUserDisabled(userId);

    match /posts/{postId} {
        allow read:  if true;
        allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                     && !isUserDisabled(userId);
    }
}
```

`isUserDislabled()` is a function that will be called in multiple places. It will `get()` the user's document to see if the user is disabled or not.

The question is, will the first call to `isUserDislabled()`, which cause a `get()` to the checking document, cost an additional read? I understand that multiple `get()` to the same document will be billed only once. However, in this case, it's the only `get()` for the particular document.

**Edit 1:** Seems like my question isn't exactly what I meant. (I'm not a native English speaker.) The question is, when the `get()` to `/users/{userId}` happens in the `match /users/{userId}` block (and not the subblock), will the `get()` cause additional read or not? In other words, between using `get()` and using `resource` variable (when it refers to the same document, of course), will it cost the same or not?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that will count as a document read. Any time a document needs to be read it counts as such, and reading it from security rules is no different than reading it from other code.

Comment: So, the request isn't merged with the original read? Like, if I read the `resource` variable, it won't count as an additional read. So, in this case, I'll be billed for 2 reads when I read `/users/{userId}`? (I will rephrase the question.)