# Firestore security rules - read count in a batch

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

If in a batch I update documents A and B and the rule for A does a `getAfter(B)` and the rule for B does a `getAfter(A)`, am I charged with 2 reads for these or not? As they are part of the batch anyway.

Example rules:

```
match /collA/{docAid} {
  allow update: if getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/collA/${docAid}/collB/{request.resource.data.lastdocBidupdated}).data.timestamp == request.time
    && ...
}

match /collA/{docAid}/collB/{docBid} {
  allow update: if getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/collA/${docAid}).data.timestamp == request.time
    && getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/collA/${docAid}).data.lastdocBidupdated == docBid
    && ...
}
```

So are these 2 reads, 1 per rule, or no reads at all?

Comment: Good question ;)

Answer (score 3):

*firebaser here*

I had to check with our team for this. The first feedback is that it doesn't count against the maximum number of calls you can make in a single security rule evaluation run.

So the thinking is that it likely also won't count against documents read, since it doesn't actually read the document. That said: I'm asking around a bit more to see if I can get this confirmed, so hold on tight.

Comment: I'm looking forward too, to see the confirmation.

Comment: Good news. Lokking forward for the confirmation. Will have one more follow-up/summary question after that

Comment: Hi @Frank, did you get the confirmation you were expected?

Comment: @Frank, so your team got back to you?

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294659/6812501

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two different documents?

If it is the case, then two reads will be performed.